# Crossing white eyed Drosophila with sepia eye

Tags: genetics, drosophila, sex-chromosome

So, I'm doing some drosophila experiments with my high schoolers and I had really poor production of wild type individuals for doing the experiment resulting in not enough to cross with everyone... I am trying the following crosses and hoping the kids can still learn from it, but wanted input from any fly-herders on what I can expect with the first two  crosses....

Sepia males x White Eye females

Sepia females x White Eye males

Dumpy males x Wild-type females

Dumpy females x Wild-type males

I don't think the gender separation will make any difference except in the white x sepia crosses since it is X-linked.
What should I get in the sepia x white crosses? Since they both control eye color and are both recessive I'm not sure. Am I correct that w is epistatic, thus should block sepia in an x-linked manner (same as if I had used wild-type instead of sepia)?
I assume the Dumpy x Wild-type will go by the books (F1 all wild-type with F2 3:1 ratio). Fingers crossed.

Answer (score 1):

I posted this on [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/biology/comments/2tz4p3/potential_teaching_moment_in_a_drosophila/) as well, so credit to km1116 for working this out. Here is his response which follows my original logic (though I'm not sure if he is right):

> female x male:
>
> w x se
>
> F1: wild-type females and white males
>
> F2: 1/4 white-eyed males, 3/16 wild-type males, 1/16 sepia males, 1/4
>   white-eyed females, 3/16 wild-type females, 1/16 sepia females
>
> se x w
>
> F1: all wild-type offspring
>
> F2: 1/4 white-eyed males, 3/16 wild-type males, 1/16 sepia males; 3/8
>   wild-type females, 1/8 sepia females
>
> wt x dp (either direction)
>
> F1: all wild-type
>
> F2: 3/4 wild-type, 1/4 dumpy

My rationale for his answer is the genotype of the cross looks like this:

X<sup>w</sup>YNN with X<sup>W</sup>X<sup>W</sup> nn , where "W" is normal eyes, "w" is white", N is Wildtype and n is sepia.